# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un EJB y un JavaBean?

Tags: java, ejb

Quisiera saber cuál o cuáles son las diferencias entre un EJB y un JavaBean?

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Desafortunadamente, esta comunidad no es un sustituto de Google. Para conocer como funciona este sitio, te invito a que visites esta presentación. También te recomiendo que uses un buscador como Google o Bing para resolver tu duda.

Comment: No me queda muy claro por qué esta pregunta está puesta en espera con motivo 'No es claro lo que pregunta' si la pregunta es absolutamente clara. Adicional a eso, SO en inglés acepta este tipo de preguntas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460048/difference-between-java-bean-and-enterprise-java-beans

Answer (score 6):

el **Java bean** es una clase java "plana", que tiene que cumplir con los siguientes requerimientos/convenciones:

- El constructor sin argumentos.
- Los atributos de clase deben ser privados.
- Cada propiedad debe tener los métodos getter setter respetando la nomenclatura.
- Debe ser serializable.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente clase **Persona** es un Java Bean

public class Persona implements java.io.Serializable {

```
private String nombre;

public Persona(){}

public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

}

Como se ve, los Java Beans son extremadamente básicos y sencillos. Cualquier programa Java, puede tener Java Beans.

Antiguamente, los IDE podían hacer **introspección** de los Java Beans gracias a que respetaban las convenciones.

Por el contrario, los EJB (Enterprise Java Beans) son objetos mucho mas complejos... Nacieron con J2EE y se necesita un **servidor de aplicaciones** como el WebSphere o el Jboss para que puedan correr.

El objetivo de la plataforma J2EE, entre otras cosas, era ofrecer el marco/la plataforma para hacer aplicaciones escalables y robustas.

Los EJB no son solamente una clase Java, sino que tiene algunos artefactos asociados (xml al principio, anotations despues), y además un **ciclo de vida propio** de ejecución dentro del **container EJB**...

Cuando se trabaja con EJB, hay que pensar si los EJB implementan las interfaz **Home** o **Remoto**, y el tipo de EJB que se va a crear: Si es de **Entidad**, de **Sesion** o **Message Driven** (menos comunes)....

Si se esta pensando en **EJB de entidades**, hay que pensar como se manejará la persistencia. Puede ser **CMP** (el container se encarga de la persistencia) o **BMP** (El Bean Maneja la persistencia).

Por último, como los EJB eran tan complejos cuando nacieron con la plataforma Java Enterprise (J2EE) donde se necesitaba un Application Server "pesado" para que puedan ejecutarse, empezó a surgir como una alternativa **Spring** como un ***container liviano*** que también solucionaba mucho de los problemas de diseño de los EJB.

A partir de la incorporación de las **anotaciones** en EJB, se simplificó mucho su uso...

Los Java Beans podemos decir que tienen que respetar la **convenciones** enumeradas mas arriba.

Mientras que los EJB son parte de un **estándar**